# CSS Gradient Background Stripes instead of Smooth gradient

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following CSS background effect as in the [following page](http://dropthebit.com/demos/fancy_input/fancyInput.html).

However, instead of getting that smooth gradient, I get something like the image shown below.

[image]

My CSS:

```
body{
     background:-webkit-radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742); background:radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742); overflow:hidden; 

}
```

I want to achieve the same result. I Have no other CSS for the body.

From Chrome inspector (for the body element)

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742);
background: radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742);
overflow: hidden;
```

I've checked both pages on the same browser and I don't use any CSS reset code. How can I achieve the same results. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried loading the page in **different browsers**? If you don't have access to other browsers, try [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/). BTW: This might also depend on the GPU you use. But most of the time the problem originates from the _rendering engine_ the browser uses. Sudden color-combinations don't harmonize, causing the shown effect.

Comment: Same in Firefox. This should work because I am loading them in the same exact browser, but I get different results.

Comment: try adding height: 100%

Comment: added 100% to the body elements, same results (I mean it doesn't work)

Comment: **Try slightly different colors.** Use the _colorpicker_ in google chromes inspector.

Comment: If I put a specific height (e.g. 900px, it works). But I need it for 100% height.

Comment: i put 100% and it renders kind of ok, but still no dark areas at the bottom and at the top. Only if I put a number it shows it as needed. wierd.

Comment: You need to add a height to both the `<html>` *and* `<body>` elements

Comment: height 100% for the HTML worked!. Thanks. Right it and I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [example page you provided](http://dropthebit.com/demos/fancy_input/fancyInput.html) works fine here in Google Chrome (v. 28.0.1500.95 m).

I've inspected the site's source. The css they use is:

```
#wrap {
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742);
  background: radial-gradient(#205983, #0A2742);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

*Did you try using all the same css rules on your site?* **Mainly notice** the `height: 100%;` rule. That might do something good.

Furthermore, **the GPU and its settings** on your machine might cause this problem to appear. But most of the time the problem originates from the rendering engine the browser uses. Sudden color-combinations don't harmonize, causing the shown effect.

**Try slightly different colors.** Use the colorpicker in Google Chromes *Inspector* (the small rectangle next to the color value of the css rule).

A recommendable **online tool to generate CSS Gradients** is: [**ColorZilla**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). It provides you with css *(or sass css if desired)* containing all common -vendor- prefixes and even adds IE support. I have positive experiences with it. Give it a try.

Good luck!

Comment: @idan-shechter **Ah I see you've got it working with the 100% height on the HTML tag.** Was writing the answer, so didn't see the comment before.

Comment: @IdanShechter Glad it helped. +1 for you that you've got it to work :-)